# iOS parse calendar for events

Tags: ios, iphone, parsing

For my school  Virginia Tech I am trying to make an iOS application where a student can view all the events happening on campus, see who is going and make their own events and invite friends to them.  VT currently has a calendar web app for their events: http://www.calendar.vt.edu/main.php?view=day
Could anyone show me the way (or the basic gist) of parsing these events, and getting their information, such as what you learn by clicking on the event for an iphone application.  What type of event it is, the price of the event, and the location.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have to do it from the front end or do you have access to the back end (servers, etc)

Comment: I just have access ot the regular website on the front end

Comment: I am not sure how to do it using the front end only. If you had an rss feed for that page you could us `NSXMLParser` and parse it out of the XML. Can you ask Virginia Tech if you can get an RSS Feed for their events.